# LWC - LightningModal does not display as a pop up and doesn't look like a modal at all

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-modal

I have a similar problem, yet I'm using the lightningModal. I also checked the element and it does have the slds-modal. I would really appreciate any idea, or if you could point me out to my error.

from the modal component:

```
<template>
    <lightning-modal-header label={header} ></lightning-modal-header>
    <lightning-modal-body> Content: {content} </lightning-modal-body>
    <lightning-modal-footer>
        <lightning-button
                label="Close"
                onclick={handleClose}
        ></lightning-button>
    </lightning-modal-footer>
</template>
```

The class:

```
import {api} from 'lwc';
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';
export default class IntegrityCheckerModalPage extends LightningModal {
    @api header ='my header';
    @api content = 'my content';

    // Return a custom value when the modal is closed with the Close button.
    // If no value is returned in the close method, then undefined is returned(Same as closing with the X button).
    handleClose() {
        this.close('return value');
    }
}
```

The datamodel's code:

1. The import:

   import IntegrityCheckerModalPage from 'c/integrityCheckerModalPage';
2. The event of the row action:

   ```
          case 'moreInfo':
               IntegrityCheckerModalPage.open({
                   label : 'hello label',
                   role : 'dialog',
                   size: 'medium',
                   description: 'MiscModal displays the message in a popup',
                   header: 'header example ' , 
                   content: 'my content'
               }).then((result) => {

                   console.log('Modal returned:' + result);
               });
   ```

   break;

I would appreciate any input.
I tried disabling the 'Lightning Web Security' and reduce the api version of the 'Lightning Locker API Version' but it didn't change anything.

This is how it looks like...

[image]

The web element:
[image]

Comment: "I have a similar problem" - similar like which problem? I've just tested your code and I get a perfectly normal modal. I have no clue where this "Cancel and close" image is from, but it's not in the source code that you provided.

Comment: sorry, I missed pasting a similar problem post :
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/371413/lwc-modal-does-not-display-as-a-pop-up

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is in a lightning-out app/a LWC displayed via a visualforce page. If that's the case, add `<apex:slds />` to the `<head>` tag of your visualforce page. That fixed it for me

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_slds.htm